# Committing sins intentionally in mind?

Tags: sin, thinking

Since I was a kid, I used to watch Naruto, I heard that you can watch anime but do not beleive in it, since I was child, I was really good at writing stories, that's why I used to make my own stories of Naruto in mind but I never commited any shirk like they used to revive dead people and even if any thought come in mind, I ask for forgiveness and distract my mind, I never believed in this and always used to think this as fictional and many times I used to say that 'Allah, I am just thinking this in fictional and it does not ever happen to me and I do not believe in it'. I also used to pray every salah except Fajr, i used to pray Fajr sometimes, Will it still be a sin?

Comment: I don’t understand. You say that you never committed any shirk in your mind with these made up stories, so what exactly are you worried about involving a sinful practice you think you’re doing?

Comment: Yes, I am pretty sure I didnt did any shirk, and even if i did it, I just at that moment distract my mind, and ask for forgiveness, but you know I sometimes only regret my sin?